# Create a custom inventory in bukkit

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

This is my code for a new Inventory in `Bukkit`.

```
package com;

import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_6_R2.inventory.CraftInventoryCustom;
import org.bukkit.inventory.*;

public class Server_Doc extends CraftInventoryCustom implements CraftingInventory, Inventory {
    InventoryHolder IH;

public Server_Doc(InventoryHolder owner, int size) {
    super(owner, size);
    ItemStack items = new ItemStack(278);
    ((Inventory) owner).addItem(items);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public ItemStack[] getMatrix() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Recipe getRecipe() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public ItemStack getResult() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setMatrix(ItemStack[] contents) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void setResult(ItemStack newResult) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
//Inventory inv = Server_Doc(IH,8); 
}
```

How could I open the inventory, once created?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you would like to open a 3x3 crafting table for a player, you can simply call `player.openWorkbench()`. Creating a custom GUI menu is a little more difficult, though. For example, using

```
public Inventory inv;

public void openGUI(Player p){
    //format: null, size of inventory (must be divisible by 9), "GUI name"
    inv = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9, "GUI Name");
    inv.setItem(0, new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND);
    p.openInventory(inv);
}
```

would open a 1x9 inventory, containing a diamond in the first slot. If you wanted to add more items, you could use

```
inv.setItem(space, ItemStack);
```

but remember, counting starts from 0, so **0** must be used to get slot **1**, and **1** must be used to get slot **2**.

To open the GUI using the above code, simply call `openGUI(player)`, where player is the player that you want to open it for.

If you would like to do something when a player clicks an item, for example let's say the diamond that we created in slot 0 (Slot 1) above, you could do this

```
@EventHandler //MAKE SURE YOU HAVE THIS
public void InventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent e){
    Player p = (Player) e.getWhoClicked();  

    if(e.getInventory().getTitle().contains("put the name of the GUI here (CAsE SEnsITivE)")){
        //Cancel the event so they can't take items out of the GUI
        e.setCancelled(true);

        if(e.getCurrentItem() == null){
            return;
        }
        //gets called when the current item's type (The item the player clicked) is a diamond
        else if(e.getCurrentItem().getType() == Material.DIAMOND){
            //send the player a message when they click it
            p.sendMessage("You clicked the diamond!");

            //call this if you want to close the inventory when they click it
            p.closeInventory();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you only have to register events in your Main file in your `onEnable()` like so

```
public void onEnable(){
    //if the code above is in your main file, use this:
    this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);

    //if it's in another class, use this:
    this.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new myClassNameHere(), this);
}
```

then just make the class that has your `inventoryClick` method in it implement `Listener`

```
public class myClassNameHere implements Listener{
```

now you have a fully functioning GUI, that when you call `openGUI(player)` player being the player you want to open the GUI for, it will open a GUI that is 1x9, having a diamond in slot 0 (Slot 1), that when clicked messages the player "You clicked the diamond!" Good luck!

Comment: It does open a gui but the crafting gui!..please help

Comment: @user3171380 In that case, the only code you would need is `p.openWorkbench`

Answer (score 0):

you do not extend your class as an Inventory but rather use this:
http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/doxygen/d4/da9/interfaceorg_1_1bukkit_1_1Server.html#a509ae49c355653a3ac68c61a7b2c5194
Example:

```
Inventory(or something) myInventory = Bukkit.getServer().createInventory(player, size);
```

and then use `myInventory.open(player);`